# How to transform affine dynamical system into linear system of difference equations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems, matrix-equations

I have a linear difference equation for a system with the form

$c_j(t+1) = \frac{b}{n} + (1-b)\sum_{i=1}^{n}B_{ij}c_i(t)$
where B is a square matrix
I'm trying to get this into the form $c(t+1) = Ac(t)$ , where $A$ is a square matrix that governs the dynamics of the system. However, I'm having trouble because of the $\frac{b}{n}$ term.

I have:

$$\left( \begin{array}{}
c_1(t+1)\\
c_2(t+1) \\
 ...\\ 
c_n(t+1)\end{array} \right) =\left( \begin{array}{}
\frac{b}{n} + (1-b)(B_{11}c_1(t) + B_{21}c_2(t) + ... + B_{n1}c_n(t))\\
\frac{b}{n} + (1-b)(B_{12}c_1(t) + B_{22}c_2(t) + ... + B_{n2}c_n(t)) \\
 ...\\ 
 \frac{b}{n} + (1-b)(B_{1n}c_1(t) + B_{2n}c_2(t) + ... + B_{nn}c_n(t))\end{array} \right)$$

I want this in the form $c(t+1) = Ac(t)$
so that I can solve the system using $c(t) = A^tc(0) $, but I'm not seeing how to achieve this form. It may be that I'm approaching this entirely incorrectly.
 If you have thoughts on how to proceed, I would very much appreciate them.

edit: I would like it specifically in the form stated above without any additions to the c vector as suggested in the answers below. If Is this even possible?

Comment: If $c(t+1)=Uc(t)+V$, note that $C(t+1)=WC(t)$, where $$C(t)=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ c(t)\end{pmatrix}\qquad W=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ V& U\end{pmatrix}$$ In your case, $c(t)$ and $V$ are of size $n\times1$, $U$ is of size $n\times n$ hence $C(t)$ is of size $(n+1)\times1$ and $W$ is of size $(n+1)\times(n+1)$, as desired.

Comment: Why the near deletion?

Comment: I wanted to rephrase something and messed up. Couldn't figure out how to bring it back, so thank you.

Comment: This page might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2055027/revisions

Comment: "Is this even possible?" Trivially not, since the transformation $c(t)\mapsto c(t+1)$ that you are considering is not linear (unless $b=0$) while every transformation $c(t)\to Ac(t)$ is linear. Two more remarks: to modify silently the question is not very cool; to avoid addressing the content of the comments/answers you received is not cool either (and might actually prevent you to progress in your understanding...).

Comment: I'm fairly new here, so I don't know the etiquette for these kinds of things. I suppose I should make a note of what I edit.

Comment: Forget the etiquette, think only common decency (or *pure logic*, if you prefer to call it like that).

Comment: I hope you find my most recent modification more appropriate

Comment: Remains the fact that you are still asking for something which was proved to you to be impossible... Do you understand the concept of a proof of nonexistence?

Comment: @Did Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Each row is multiplied by (1-b) except for the first term, we can therefore factor 1-b out to get:

$$\left( \begin{array}{c}
c_1(t+1)\\
c_2(t+1) \\
\vdots\\ 
c_n(t+1)\end{array} \right) =  (1-b)\left( \begin{array}{c}
\frac{b}{n(b-1)} + (B_{11}c_1(t) + B_{21}c_2(t) + ... + B_{n1}c_n(t))\\
\frac{b}{n(b-1)} + (B_{12}c_1(t) + B_{22}c_2(t) + ... + B_{n2}c_n(t)) \\
 \vdots\\ 
 \frac{b}{n(b-1)} + (B_{1n}c_1(t) + B_{2n}c_2(t) + ... + B_{nn}c_n(t))\end{array} \right)$$

Now let $\cases{c_0(t) = 1\\ B_{0k} = \frac{b}{n(b-1)}}$ and what happens then?

Comment: Yes, I've thought about that solution. However, that makes the matrix A non-square.

Comment: @Mady $A$ will be square ($n+1\times n+1$, specifically) if you enlarge the $c$-vector to include $c_0(t)=1$ as its first entry.

Comment: @Semiclassical I'm seeing that A has dimensions n x n+1; where does the extra row of the matrix come in?

Comment: @Mady: We can try to add a new row in such a way that it makes multiplication well defined (square matrix) and does not change the rest of the intended behaviour.